# How can I get the WP-CLI eval-file command to report errors to stderr?

Tags: wp-cli

I'm writing a one-off script to update some posts in the database. Whenever there is an error in my script, it fails silently.

I've followed the suggestions in this Github issue without success:

https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/706

I've also tried running my script with [debug set to true](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/config/):

```
wp --debug eval-file my-script.php
```

And I've tried [setting `WP_DEBUG` to true](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/config/#config-files) in `wp-cli.yaml`:

```
# Subcommand defaults (e.g. `wp eval-file config`)
eval-file config:
    extra-php: |
        define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Still, deathly silence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following lines to the top of your script, as recommended in [Github issue](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/706#issuecomment-156542189), should report any runtime errors:

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

However, it will not report syntax errors, which is a big headache as you try to write your script. This is my workaround for that:

- Add following line to bottom of my script:

  ```
  // my-script.php
  <?php
  ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  global $wpdb;

  // rest of script

  echo "Script complete.\n";
  ```
- Make changes to script.

  ```
  // my-script.php
  <?php
  ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  global $wpdb;

  // rest of script
  derp-some-invalid-syntax...

  echo "Script complete.\n";
  ```
- Run script:

  ```
  $ wp --debug eval-file my-script.php
  ```
- If I don't see `Script complete.`, run php linter:

  ```
  $ php -l my-script.php

  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in my-script.php on line 7
  Errors parsing my-script.php
  ```
- Fix syntax errors.
- Re-run script.